# Is there a keyboard shortcut for the user's home directory or Program Files in windows explorer?

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, cross-platform

<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> in **Finder** will take me to my home (~/) directory, similarly <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> will take me to /Applications. Is there an equivalent for **Explorer**?

I know in Powershell I can use `cd ~`, but typing `~` into the address bar of an Explorer window opens up my web browser. Typing `%USERPROFILE%` works, but it's hardly what you'd call a shortcut.

There's also the trick of setting an environmental variable like %H%, but hitting <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to open an explorer window, <kbd>F4</kbd> to open the address bar, and typing <kbd>%</kbd><kbd>H</kbd><kbd>%</kbd> to go to your home dir is still a bit clumsier than OSX's three button chord that takes you right there.

I'm thinking that there isn't anything like this built into the OS, so is it a job for Autohotkey?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows, you can create a shortcut to the folder of your choice, name it as desired and assign keyboard shortcut keys. For example, if you want a shortcut to your user profile, and your user name is "stib":

1. Right-click where you want to create it, e.g. *Desktop*, and select *New -> Shortcut*
2. Enter *C:\Users\stib*; assign a name as desired.
3. Right-click on the new shortcut, select *Properties*.
4. Assign *Shortcut key:* e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> for "stib".

You can access Explorer using that shortcut at any time [unless an application preemptively steals that key combination] by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, or by clicking on the icon.

Please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Add good, but I wouldn't recommend `Ctrl+Alt+Letter` because many applications use it. `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Letter` is best you can do to avoid conflicts.

Comment: I've actually just made a bunch of keyboard shortcuts with AutoHotKey: `win+h` for home, `win+a` for applications… er program files, etc. Saves the worry about conflicts (since I use software like After Effects and Lightwave there aren't many key combinations left that aren't conflicted).

Comment: @stib – with AHK, you can use `AppsKey+Letter`, it is 100% conflict-free :)